# isort will not parse directories anymore, are there variants?

Tags: python, isort

Used isort for a while, but now it starts complaining about the fact that a directory is a directory??

```
venv/bin/isort --diff --check src tests
WARNING: Unable to parse file src due to [Errno 21] Is a directory: '[...]/src'
WARNING: Unable to parse file tests due to [Errno 21] Is a directory: '[...]/tests'
```

Are there more than one variants of isort??

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-rc`/`--recursive` flags.

```
$ isort --help
...
  -c, --check-only      Checks the file for unsorted / unformatted imports and prints them to the command line without modifying the file.
...
  -df, --diff           Prints a diff of all the changes isort would make to a file, instead of changing it in place
...
  -rc, --recursive      Recursively look for Python files of which to sort imports
...
```

So in your case the following line should work (`--check` was replaced with `--check-only`).

```
$ venv/bin/isort --check-only --diff --recursive src tests
```

You can use even shorter form.

```
$ venv/bin/isort -c -df -rc src tests
```

Check [this comment](https://github.com/PyCQA/isort/issues/805#issuecomment-460451121) from GitHub repo.